# Why won't IE css fix work for internet explorer8? ie statement end if

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, if-statement

Hi I've applied an ie fix for my site but it doesn't work for ie8. Do I have to be more specific?

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/AEBP_Homepage_12887/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks for your help
Regards
Judi

Comment: The stylesheet is accessible? What happens if you open the file /AEBP_.../ie.css directly in the browser (FF preferably)?

Comment: Or have you catched the Chrome frame virus? http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<!--[if IE]>` or `<!--[if IE 8]>` will be just fine for IE8, as long as your ie.css is working properly

Comment: Thanks, yeh I've just tested it and it works, http://www.spoon.net/browsers/ lies beware!

Comment: Is it possible, that Spoon was called Xenocode not this long ago?